# Duplicate post notice disappears on "click to reload"

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, live-refresh

I'm generally behind a proxy, so live refresh doesn't work.

However, today(no proxy) I noticed that when you click-to-reload a question due to edits, the "possible dupe" banner/post notice disappears. I'm guessing that this isn't intentional.

Could this be fixed? It is a rather trivial bug, but a bug nonetheless.

Comment: @asad oops. That didn't show up in the suggested list :s Thanks for finding that :)

Comment: No probs. Not *entirely* sure if yours is the same, but I gave it a readthrough and it seems pretty close. You should check anyway.